# TF215097: An error occured while initializing a build for build definition

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We just installed TFS2013 Update 2 on a brand new server with server 2008 r2 on it. At one moment in time I was able to run builds for my projects but now I can't and I don't know why or what even changed. The explination will get a little winded so sorry. Here is the full exception that i see every time. All of my projects use the CMMI process, so out of curiousity I made a new project called Hello World Test that uses the Agile template. Made a new build, committed my code and sure enough just like all my other projects I get this error. There are 3 accounts in our TFS server, 2 are admin and 1 is a contributor. I'm one of the 2 admins, but both of us have same problem. I've even logged on as the system admin and tried kicking off a build and got same error.

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Hello World Test\WpfApplication1: 
Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: VS30063: You are not authorized to access http://foo.bar.com:8050. (type VssUnauthorizedException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.HttpClientExtensions.<DownloadFileFromTfsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

After getting this error about 100x I checked the Application logs to see if i could glean any sort of information and the only thing I could see was that during creation of the build server was this `Failed to add the build service account 'CORP\Administrator' to Windows Group 'IIS_IUSRS'. Details: Group does not exist.` I tried changing the build server user and each time i get the same Warning message in the event logs. I'm almost 100% sure this is the problem. Now what I find odd about this particular error is that I can see IIS_IUSRS in active directory but i keep getting that error. Anyone have any clue as to why i'm getting this error? What information can I get anyone to help figure this out?

Comment: Is the account that you're using for your build service a member of the Team Project Collection service accounts group? It's very important that it is.

Comment: I've just had this issue - does the account you're running TFS as have an expired password? We were running as Administrator, as soon as the password expired we started getting this error. Setting the "Password never expires flag" seemed to fix it.

Comment: The password was recently changed, however I'm not sure of being a member. I have however deleted the one build service and put my user as the build account, and still got the same problem

Comment: @DanielMann I checked the Admin account and he is a part of the `project collection admins`, `project collection build service accounts`, `Team Foundation Admins`, `Administrators`, `Domain Admins`, and `Enterprise Admins`

Comment: @tomdavies I double checked the administrator account in active directory and the password never expires flag is set.